# A linear transfomation $h:\Bbb R^n\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ is orthogonal iff carries a base $\mathcal V$ in an orthonormal base $\mathcal V'$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

What shown below is a reference form *Analysis on Manifolds* by James Munkres.

[image]

So I want understand better the final statement. Indeed if the matrix $A$ is calculated only respcect the canonical base then clearly the transformation $h$ carries the canonical base in an orthonormal base but I don't understand if $A$ is calculated respect the bases $\mathcal V:=\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ and $\mathcal W:=\{w_1,...,w_n\}$ then the statement holds again. Then if we use another dot product the statement is generally false, right? So could someone help me, please?

Comment: If $A,B$ are orthogonal matrices, then so is $B A^T$.

Comment: @copper.hat Okay, and so?

Comment: The final statement is not true for any two bases. After all, I can take *any* invertible linear transformation $f$, some base $\mathcal V:=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ and a base $\mathcal W:=\{f(v_1),\dots,f(v_n)\}$, and then the matrix representation of $f$ with respect to those two bases is the identity matrix, which is orthogonal. But not every invertible linear transformation is orthogonal, so the statement can't hold for arbitrary bases.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: Some work required. Let $A$ be the matrix that maps from the canonical basis to the $V$ basis and $B$ the same for the $W$ basis. Then $BA^T$ is the matrix that maps the $V$ basis to the $W$ basis.

Comment: @Chrystomath No, sorry.

Comment: @copper.hat However if we use another dot product the statement could be false, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro: The inner product defines orthogonality, so if you change the product then the matrices are not necessarily orthogonal with respect to the new product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement says that if $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ is an orthogonal matrix, the columns of $A$, namely$Ae_1,\dots,Ae_n$, forms an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb R^n$. I don't understand what do you mean by *if $A$ is calculated respect to the basis...*, but it is true that if $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is any other orthonormal basis for $\mathbb R^n$ (not necessarily the standard basis) then $Av_1,\dots,Av_n$ is again an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb R^n$. This is because if $B$ is the matrix whose $j$-th column is $v_j$, then $B$ and $AB$ are orthogonal matrices, and then note that $Av_j = (AB)e_j$. Is this that you are looking for?

Comment: However if we use another dot product the statement could be false, right?

Comment: That's right, because the way we multiply matrices is closely related to the standard inner product.

Comment: Consider the identity matrix and choose another inner product.